# how do i get products where expiring date today and will end tomorrow?

Tags: wordpress, post, select

how do I get products where expiring date today and will end tomorrow?

**Query Here**

```
$current_date = date('d/m/y/'); 
$future_date = strtotime($current_date, "+ 1 day");
$today_date = strtotime($current_date);

$sql = "SELECT distinct wposts.*
                FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
                WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
                AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND wposts.post_type = 'products'
                AND  wpostmeta.meta_value =$today_date AND 
                wpostmeta.meta_value <=$future_date
                ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC";
```

**value in wpostmeta.meta_value table**

```
1520380800, 07/03/18
```

**Database**

[image]

Comment: 07/03/18 what is this date inwpostmeta.meta_value table ?

Comment: in the meta_value like this `1520380800` date `07/03/18` convert into `strtotime`

Comment: Do you want to convert 1520380800 into 07/03/18

Comment: no, basically I want get all products which are expired today and tomorrow with `strtotime`  time?

Comment: Time to start using wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query which is available in WC 3.0 https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Comment: but i don't have woo commerce

Comment: Why are you using a custom SQL query instead of the [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class? It would be trivial to run that with a meta_query

Comment: but how can I get products with wp_query according to my requirements?

Comment: Please help me thanks